# View one tag before article title in module

Tags: tags, title, article, joomla3.2

How can i put one Tag name before an article title in mod_articles_category joomla 3.0.

All articles have 5 tags including Tag video or picture.
I will view the Tag video or picture before the article title.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [layout override](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_2.5) for that module which you would assign from the module's Advanced tab. This will allow you to edit the code as desired to place your tag code where you want it.